# Was the economy of Dinohattan ever explored?

Tags: economics, super-mario-brothers, super-mario-bros-1993

The 1993 *Super Mario Bros.* film explores a parallel Earth in which dinosaurs survived and evolved intelligence. In the present day of the film, the dinosaurs' planet's lack of resources is mentioned by Koopa as a primary reason for conquering the humans' Earth. The cars used by the intelligent dinosaurs are electric, seemingly implying a lack of oil. In addition, the globe in Koopa's office as well as the scenery outside the city of Dinohattan portray a barren ecology with very little water and essentially no agriculture.

This barren world would seemingly lack, from a worldbuilding perspective, any way of supporting an intelligent, urban civilization. Was the economic basis of Dinohattan ever explored? Do the citizens have some way of generating food or energy, or do they even do anything other than party and kowtow to Koopa?

It would make sense for energy production in Dinohattan to be performed by the Goombas, but then there would have to be a means of feeding such a large workforce, which there doesn't seem to be.

I do realize that the film was a box-office Bob-omb that turned Nintendo off from making live-action movies for a quarter century, but that doesn't mean that I didn't miss a hint somewhere in the film or that there isn't some supplementary material out there that explores the economy on at least a superficial level.

Being a standalone film, I don't see much of a "canon" to worry about. If there is any material at all outside the film that could be seen as even remotely reliable, I would count it. For example, if there was an official President Koopa toy that came with a back-of-the-box blurb of "Koopa devastated his planet's environment by too much tooting on warp whistles, so he has turned his sights on our world to restore his before Dinohattan's reserves run dry.", that's a great answer.

Comment: I guess your best bet is checking out the more or less official sequel comic, where http://www.smbthecomic.com/comic/chapter-2-page-12/ states "On this page we introduce one of the greatest changes to Dinohattan since the Mario Bros. left: a central park filled with a tropical garden! Now, the big question is how did all of the flora get there? We all know that the parallel world in the film was dying out, so plantlife doesn’t make a lot of sense. You’ll all just have to read on to find out!" (I haven't read much further yet)

Comment: ...I read on (not much to go actually, seems to have been abandoned), and basically they merely tapped into the planet's last water reservoirs for those plants. Not much about economy at all I'm afraid